# Join tables based on dates with check

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in PostgreSQL:

`Demans_for_parts`:

```
   demandid partid  demanddate        quantity 
    40       125     01.01.17          10
    41       125     05.01.17          30
    42       123     20.06.17          10
```

`Orders_for_parts`:

```
  orderid  partid orderdate        quantity 
   1        125     07.01.17     15
   54       125     10.06.17     25
   14       122     05.01.17     30
```

Basicly Demans_for_parts says what to buy and Orders_for_parts says what we bought. We can buy parts which do not list on Demans_for_parts.

I need a report which shows me all parts in Demans_for_parts and how many weeks past since the most recent matching row in Orders_for_parts. note quantity field is irrelevent here,

The expected result is (if more than one row per part show the oldes):

```
partid   demanddate        weeks_since_recent_order
125     01.01.17                  2   (last order is on 10.06.17)
123     20.06.17                Unhandled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tricky part is getting one row per table.  But that is easy using `distinct on`.  Then you need to calculate the months.  You can use `age()` for this purpose:

```
select dp.partid, dp.date,
       (extract(year from age(dp.date, op.date))*12 +
        extract(month from age(dp.date, op.date))
       ) as months
from (select distinct on (dp.partid) dp.*
      from demans_for_parts dp
      order by dp.partid, dp.date desc
     ) dp left join
     (select distinct on (op.partid) op.*
      from Orders_for_parts op
      order by op.partid, op.date desc
     ) op
     on dp.partid = op.partid;
```

Comment: what is the meanining of months in this case? i don't understand why it shows negative values. What i want to see is the weeks past since the last time we bought the part meaning the weeks past since the most recent (new) record in Orders_for_parts for this part

Comment: @user2641077 . .. Had the dates in the wrong order.

Comment: thx, I'm still haveing troubles with it. the dp.commitdate  desc is incorect it should be ASC because i want the oldest demand... after I change that i cant make the age works properly (in weeks value)

Answer (score 0):

smth like?

```
with o as (
  select distinct partid, max(orderdate) over (partition by partid)
  from Orders_for_parts
)
, p as (
  select distinct partid, min(demanddate) over (partition by partid)
  from Demans_for_parts
)
select p.partid, min as demanddate, date_part('day',o.max - p.min)/7
from p
left outer join o on (p.partid = o.partid)
;
```

Comment: it gives me many rows per part... it should be no more than 1 row per part